# SQL query want to eliminate the same data in multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

```
     **Table :1**                                         **Table:2**          

 id folio num  num1  num2  num3  num4  num5           id  number  folio
                                                      -------------------
 ------------------------------------------
 1   abcde 1000  2000  3000  4000  5000  0           1    6000    abcde
                                                     2    1000    abcde
 2   abcde 6000                                      3    7000    abcde
                                                     4    5000    abcde
                                                     5    10000   abcde




 output want to be 

 id number folio
 ---------------
 1   7000   abcde
 2   10000  abcde

 ----------------------
 I USED THE SQL QUERY OF 
 SELECT * FROM Table2 WHERE id_t = 'abcde'
 AND  number NOT IN(SELECT CONCAT(num,num1,num2,num3,num4,num5) FROM Table1 WHERE id_t = 'abcde')

 -----------------------------------------------
```

SQL query want to eliminate the same data in multiple tables.

Want to compare two table but different fields ,if data in that table it want to eliminate only the unique data want to show

1.table2 number(field) want to check table1 num,num1,num2,num3,num4,num5(field)
2.values which was not in table 1 alone want to display

Comment: Any time you have enumerated column names (above '2', say), something's probably gone wrong somewhere. See normalisation.

Answer (score 0):

Doing a LEFT OUTER JOIN on a sub query. The sub query returns every num for each folio.

The WHERE clause then ensures only rows are returned where there is no match (ie, nothing matching found in the sub query).

```
SELECT Table2.id,
        Table2.number,
        Table2.folio
FROM Table2
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT folio, num AS aNum FROM table1
    UNION 
    SELECT folio, num1 AS aNum FROM table1
    UNION 
    SELECT folio, num2 AS aNum FROM table1
    UNION 
    SELECT folio, num3 AS aNum FROM table1
    UNION 
    SELECT folio, num4 AS aNum FROM table1
    UNION 
    SELECT folio, num5 AS aNum FROM table1
) sub0
ON Table2.folio = sub0.folio
AND Table2.number = sub0.num
WHERE sub0.folio IS NULL
```

Alternative that might make better use of index:-

```
SELECT Table2.id,
        Table2.number,
        Table2.folio
FROM Table2
LEFT OUTER JOIN table1 t1a ON Table2.folio = t1a.folio AND Table2.number = t1a.num
LEFT OUTER JOIN table1 t1b ON Table2.folio = t1b.folio AND Table2.number = t1b.num1
LEFT OUTER JOIN table1 t1c ON Table2.folio = t1c.folio AND Table2.number = t1c.num2
LEFT OUTER JOIN table1 t1d ON Table2.folio = t1d.folio AND Table2.number = t1d.num3
LEFT OUTER JOIN table1 t1e ON Table2.folio = t1e.folio AND Table2.number = t1e.num4
LEFT OUTER JOIN table1 t1f ON Table2.folio = t1f.folio AND Table2.number = t1f.num5
WHERE COALESCE(t1a.num, t1b.num1, t1c.num2, t1d.num3, t1e.num4, t1f.num5) IS NULL
```

EDIT

Another way to do it, although not keen on this one. Uses a sub query to concatenate up all the values of the various num fields, and then GROUP_CONCAT to do that over various lines. Then joins against that using FIND_IN_SET. Likely to be inefficient, but for amusement here it is:-

```
SELECT Table2.id,
        Table2.number,
        Table2.folio
FROM Table2
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT folio, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS(',', num, num1, num2, num3, num4, num5)) AS all_num
    FROM table1
    GROUP BY folio
) sub0
ON Table2.folio = sub0.folio
AND FIND_IN_SET(Table2.number, sub0.all_num) > 0
WHERE sub0.folio IS NULL
```

Comment: It works as expected. Thank you all for your help and support.